Multiple Livewire components in Filament 3 resource gives console error uncaught Snapshot missing
in my Laravel Filament v3 resource i have three Livewire custom components. The edit page loads with components, so far so good. But when i do something unrelated, for instance opening a delete confirmation modal (can also be clicking on relation tab), two of the components break with error message:
livewire.js?id=239a5c52:4437 Uncaught Snapshot missing on Livewire component with id: jMDrgTOxz321azWwuPDI
When i just have one component on the page there is no problem at all. So, it seems the DOM can't keep track of which component is which. How do i fix this?
I tried adding a ->key('component-one') to each component (suggested by chatgpt4) but didn't help.
I simplified my setup and the problem still exists. Simplified setup:
public function form(Form $form): Form {
    return $form->schema([
        Livewire::make('component-one'),
        Livewire::make('component-two'),
        Livewire::make('component-three'),
    ])
}

Each component has a Class in App\Livewire:
<?php
namespace App\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;

class ComponentOne extends Component
{
    public function render(){
        return view('livewire.component-one');
    }
}

And a blade file component-one.blade.php:
<div>Hi i a component 1</div>

In Filament 3, form is not static.
public function form(Form $form): Form


Read the docs:
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/upgrade-guide
EDITED:
Another point, I'm not sure what you trying to do.
You are using a Livewire component directly as a Form Field, you can't do that. You can use the default Fields (https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/getting-started#available-fields), or create a custom field (https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/custom). But, for create a custom field you need follow the docs.

Yes you are right. This was actually not in my code, but mistakenly put it in this example. I edited it. However, it's also not the fix to my problem. Thanks for noticing it!

@Daan, You are using a Livewire component directly as a Form Field, you can't do that. You can use the default Fields (https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/getting-started#available-fields), or create a custom field (https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/custom). But, for create a custom field you need follow the docs.

@guilano Ah makes sense, since i can find little documentation on this. It works for one Livewire component though! But I will rebuild it as a custom component! Thanks for now!
